# Is there any good Python tutorial/guide to use XML-RPC with Last.fm API?

Tags: python, web-services, xml-rpc

I'm new to XML-RPC and I would like to know if there is any good tutorial to use XML-RPC with the Last.fm API.

Is it possible to call the API methods using the xmlrpclib module like in the following example?

```
import xmlrpclib
myserver = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code looks just fine.

You might not know this, but most XML-RPC endpoints (such as Last.fm's) support [XML-RPC introspection](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/introspection.html). For instance, if you want to find out what methods it exposes, do this:

```
import xmlrpclib
svc = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/')
print svc.system.listMethods()
```

And you'll be given a list of the methods exposed by the XML-RPC endpoint.

By the way, that bit of code up there demonstrates how to use a `ServerProxy` object to call a method exposed by the endpoint it's tied to, in this case, the `system.listMethods` method. If you wanted to call the `user.getTopTags` (as demonstrated on the [API documentation homepage](http://www.last.fm/api/xmlrpc)) method exposed by Last.fm, you'd do this:

```
print svc.user.getTopTags({'user': 'foo', 'api_key': 'bar'})
```

Dead simple! Of course, you'll need an API key from Last.fm before you can use the API.

Comment: Did you verify that it supports XML-RPC introspection? As of January 2011 it doesn't (`Invalid Method`); perhaps support was removed?

Comment: Sorry about not replying sooner. There's no way to check if it supports introspection other than attempting it. That kind of functionality is exactly what introspection is meant for. they may have changed the XML-RPC libraries they use from ones that automatically support introspection to ones that don't. it's a pity, as introspection is a useful feature, and one where the server libraries can do most of the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Now its not a good time to work on last.fm's api. They are changing it in a few days I think.

Answer (score 1):

## pylast

---

#### Last fm library in Python

The [pylast library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylast/0.3.1) is a good choice for this work.

The library has a very large set of functionality covering all the major parts of the [last.fm API](http://www.last.fm/api).

#### Functionality

This includes: Albums, Artists, Auth, Events, Geo, Libraries, Playlists, Tags, Tasteometer ratings, Users and Venues.

Using a library such as this means that a lot of the work is done for you, so you dont spend time reinventing the wheel. (The library iteself is 3,000+ lines of code).

#### License

Because of the license which this library is released under, it is possible to modify the code yourself.

There is also a community of people working to hightlight any bugs in the library at http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=66150&atid=513503

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylast/0.3.1

or if u do it by your own you can check the code...

Comment: I've tried to use it but it lacks documentation... Right now I'm trying to learn something from the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your example of using the xmlrpclib looks fine.

Pylast is probably not the best beginner example.  From Python, I think the simplest options are to use XML-RPC as you mentioned, or the [REST API](http://www.last.fm/api/rest) with the JSON response format and [simplejson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson) to decode the ouput.