# How can I train a tensorflow model on another local computer and get its return value?

Tags: python, tensorflow, server

So currently I have one computer running MacOS and another computer with a GPU running windows. What's the best way to send data (in this case, 2 images or links to images) from the Mac to the Windows computer, train a model with Tensorflow on the Windows computer, then send the output of the model (another image) back to the Mac? They are both on the same network.

I found a couple solutions so far but I'm not sure which one is optimal:

- [Using Pyro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029157/how-can-i-send-python-code-to-another-machine-to-be-executed)
- Installing linux on the Windows machine and then SSH'ing onto it like a server

I'm new to setting up any server kind of things so any tips would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like:

1. Connecting to the machine with the GPU via ssh
2. Open a [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) session or something similar so that all that is printed and will be printed inside the terminal is not lost when I disconnect from the ssh. To create the session (after you have installed tmux) the command to write in the terminal is: `tmux new -s my_session`
3. Launch the training inside that tmux session.
4. Detach from the session with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> and then <kbd>d</kbd>.
5. Disconnect from the ssh and re-connect from time to time to check the training. After re-connecting to the ssh you just have to attach to the session with `tmux attach -t my_session` to see what was outputted from the training while you were away.
6. When the training is finished I ssh the output folder containing images, logs etc. to my other machine.

Surely there are more automated solutions, but this one works the best for me.